# PowerShell: In a text file, make this line part of the previous line

Tags: powershell, text-processing

The circumstances that lead to this request are not hugely important *(read: please don't give me pointers on how to avoid this situation, I have tried them)* but I have an engine producing text files. As an example, these files normally look like this:

```
ENTRY: XYZ
COMMENT: This is a comment
ENTRY: 123
INTEGER: 4
```

Sometimes, however, the data we process contains line breaks, so the text files look like this:

```
ENTRY: XYZ
COMMENT: This is a comment
that spans over multiple lines
just to make life difficult
ENTRY: 123
```

What I'm looking for is some PowerShell that can process an entire text file and say, "for lines not containing a `:` character, make this line part of the line before it, potentially replacing the break with `::` or something to make it clear".
The sought end result would be:

```
ENTRY: XYZ
COMMENT: This is a comment :: that spans over multiple lines :: just to make life difficult
ENTRY: 123
```

So far I've been using `Get-Content | % {$_ etc}`, but the % splits things into individual lines. I don't believe `%` or `?` has any sentience of context so it's not going to be possible to say "where object match xyz make it part of the last object".

I spent a long time trying to use line numbers. My pseudo-code was:

- while the document contains lines that do not contain a colon, get the line number of the first line not containing a colon
- set the previous line number to contain both its data and the data of the offending line

However, the former action would upset the number of lines, meaning every time I made this adjustment I'd need to recalculate the individual line numbers. Add to this that the "while the document contains lines that don't start with a colon" can potentially be a very system-intensive process (these documents can be very large) and it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Is there reason you want to use Powershell and not something like Notepad++ to edit the file?

Comment: @DavidPostill I have edited the question.
Reddy: automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a regex-based solution:

```
(Get-Content -Raw test.txt) -Replace '\n([^\n:]+)(?=\n)', ' :: $1' | Out-File test.txt
```

First you load the whole file with `-Raw` flag. Then the regex matches a new line (`\n`), characters that aren't newline or `:` captured in a group `([^\n:]+)` and lastly we have a positive lookahead for a newline `(?=\n)` that makes sure to stop at it but skips it for the full match so that next `\n` is matched for next line. Then we have a proper replacement using the captured group and output it to the same file.

Comment: Wow. Amazing. Thank you very much.